# WSO2 - Forward response from REST (called from WSO2) to JMS queue

Tags: api, rest, queue, wso2, jms

I've faced an issue, with trying to forward message, returned from my custom REST end-point, into JMS queue.

I wanted to implement something like:

1. *SMTH CUSTOM IS PUSHING MESSAGE TO WSO2 JMS QUEUE called **testQueue***
2. WSO2 is retrieving this message, and once there is an message, it's pushing this message next to custom REST service:
3. Becasue I've defined **receive** to **testResponse** inside **send** section, I'm able to log reponse from **REST API** inside **testResponse**.
4. Now I'm stuck, as I'm trying to somehow push response from **REST API** next, to let say second JMS queue, called **testQueue2**.

I've already tried with **call** tags inside my custom **sequence** (called **testReponse**), but it's just not executing at all (I've also tried for test, just to execute second REST API inside, to be just sure, if it's not something with executing of JMS itself...):

Any ideas, how I can move response from called **REST API** on to JMS queue?

Thanks.

```
<proxy name="testQueue" startOnLoad="true" transports="jms">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <send receive="testResponse">
                <endpoint>
                    <http format="rest" method="POST" uri-template="http://localhost/customRestAPI?message=test" />
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence />
    </target>
</proxy>

<sequence name="testResponse">
    <log level="full" />
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an "Out Flow" mediation extension as explained [here.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions#AddingMediationExtensions-Creatingper-APIextensions)